# Silverlight RichTextBox: How to set custom font from resource/stream?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

Does anybody know how to set the font within a `RichTextBox` from a `Stream`?

`TextBlock` and `TextBox` do have the option to set the `FontSource`,
but classes like `Run`, `Paragraph` and the whole `RichTextBox` miss that. :(
Any reason for that?

Is there any known way to achieve that?
I already tried to set the whole source URI within the `FontFamily`
but that does not seem to work on external sources,
just for internal URI addresses like `/SilverlightFontTest;component/GRAFFITO_01.ttf#Graffito`.

I cannot find any further information what to try next or how to go on,
please help me.

Kind Regards,
Bastian

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom font in a Silverlight control but if it isn't installed on the user's machine, it must be stored in your project somewhere. I've done this by creating a "fonts" folder. You must also set each font file's "build action" to "resource" in the Properties window.

Then you can refer to these fonts in your code. In the silverlight richtextbox you can specify a FontFamily like this:

`Dim oFontFamily as New FontFamily("fontFolderName/FontFileName.otf#FontName")
myRichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.FontFamilyPoeprty, oFontFamily)`

So for Helvetica LT STD Roman, it would go like:

`Dim oFontFamily as new FontFamily("fonts/HelveticaLTSTD-Roman.otf#Helvetica LT Std")`

You can get the actual font name ("Helvetica LT Std") by manually opening the font file.

From the previous example, I've got my font files stored in a folder called "fonts" in my Silverlight project.

It's not the most straightforward solution, but it does work. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, this actually works,
but it does not solve the problem to set a font ressource from a stream.